# Javascript: How to toggle hide between 2 objects?

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

i basically have the script done but i might be overlooking something super simple. I'm toggling between hiding ObjectA and ObjectB. the script is like this:

```
var click = false;

TouchGestures.onTap(facemesh0).subscribe(function(){
    if(click) {
      ObjectA.hidden = true;
      ObjectB.hidden = false;
      click = false;
    } else{
      ObjectB.hidden = true;
      ObjectA.hidden = false;
      click = true;
    }
});
```

but the problem is that it only starts toggling on the second click.

Comment: What is the value of ObjectA.hidden and ObjectB.hidden before first click?

Comment: `ObjectAhidden` is a typo

Comment: @Nisarg ObjectA.hidden = false; ObjectB.hidden = true;

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because you start with objectA.hidden= true and ObjectB.hidden=false

What about the following code that does not need the click Boolean ?

```
TouchGestures.onTap(facemesh0).subscribe(function() {
    ObjectA.hidden = !ObjectA.hidden;
    ObjectB.hidden = !ObjectB.hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite straight forward. You can refer to the following codes.

```js
// Let's define some state for demo purposes.
let ObjectA = false;
let ObjectB = true;

console.log(`Object A: ${ObjectA}`)
console.log(`Object B: ${ObjectB}`)

function toggle() {
  ObjectA = !ObjectA
  ObjectB = !ObjectB
  
  console.log(`Current Object A: ${ObjectA}`)
  console.log(`Current Object B: ${ObjectB}`)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```